# Boost input mic under Debian

Tags: linux, usb, audio, debian, microphone

I'm running Debian Jessie Lite (without X) on RPi3. I connected an external USB microphone and I set the volume to maximum using both alsamixer and pactl set-source-volume.

Anyway the actual recording volume is still to low. I tried with sox rec. To be sure of my mic I connected it to a Windows machine and it shows a boost option in the mixer. In this way the audio is very good.

A part of the two commands above, is there something other I could try to turn up the volume of USB mic in Linux?

Comment: From [this](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/pulseaudio-discuss/2015-April/023738.html) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/474349) I gather I'd tried setting the volume of the mic's source above 100% using `pactl` because that appears to be what the "mic boost" option really does. On my machine with X, `pavucontrol` displays like 200% scale for the mic's slider.

Comment: I will try and I will write back the result. I have a bit of confusion about sinks/sources. The examples in the links you provided say: `pactl set-sink-volume 0 70%`. But for me a microfone is an input, thus a *source*. Instead is a *sink*, why? It's not obvious for me!

Comment: Your mic should be "source" while what plays the sould should be "sink" -- that's how I understand it. `pactl` has the `set-sink-input-volume`  and `set-source-volume` and `set-source-output-volume` commands so may be you should check these out.

Comment: I also understand in this way, but the second link explicitly says: "List mic sink", "Set mic sink volume", "Make sure to setting mic volume you have to use mic sink index number"...